# get rows by time regardless of date in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data as follows:

```
Col1,ColDate
a,2020-09-11 08:43:00
b,2020-09-12 09:43:00
c,13-09-2020 09:43:00
d,09/16/2020 10:43:00
e,09/19/2020 12:43:00
f,09/12/2020 15:43:00
```

Intention is to get all rows between 0000 and 0900 hours, regardless of the date and its format. In pandas

I am trying the following:

```
df[df["ColDate"].between('00:00:00','09:00:00')]
```

I get an empty dataframe.

**EDIT**

I am aware of the between_time function which uses the time in the index. Is there an alternative to this? I do not want to modify the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.between_time`:

```
df["ColDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ColDate"]) # If not in datetime already
new_df = df.set_index("ColDate").between_time("00:00:00", "09:00:00")
print(new_df.reset_index())
```

Or other way around:

```
new_df = df[df["ColDate"].dt.time.between(*pd.to_datetime(["00:00:00", "09:00:00"]).time)]
```

Output:

```
              ColDate Col1
0 2020-09-11 08:43:00    a
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But can we use something other than between_time

Answer (score 2):

In case 'ColDate' is not yet in datetime format:

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df['ColDate']).dt.hour.isin(range(0,9))]
```

Otherwise just

```
df[df['ColDate'].dt.hour.isin(range(0,9))]
```

Comment: I tested it yes. In range(0,9) the 9 is excluded so '09:43:00' will not appear. However '09:00:00' is excluded as well with this method, I don't know whether this is desired.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I need 09:00:00 to be included